# Sticky Header and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, header, less

**Background:** I am using Bootstraps Grid system but there is a specific column that I want to create a sticky header (see the `<header>` element below line #4) in that does not move when the user scrolls.

**What I am seeing:** The header is not being contained by its column parent and the next row is hidden behind it.

**Question:** Is it possible to create a pure css sticky element that is contained inside of a parent element?

**Example of code can be found HERE:**  http://www.bootply.com/Q3Nnqw0yK9

```css
.col-md-2, col-xs-2 {
  16.66666667%;
}
.col-md-8, col-xs-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}
.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.child-header {
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
   
 .affix {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"></div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8" id="main-region">
  <div class="card">
    <header class="child-header affix row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h3 class="panel-title" style="line-height: 34px; color:#757575;">
                        Profile your Organization
                    </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 button-set" id="card-header-button-region" style="height:50px;">
        <button type="button" id="org_profile_next" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised pull-right" data-perm="8">
          <div class="ico-btn">
            <i class="material-icons navigate">navigate_before</i>
          </div>
        </button>
        <button type="button" id="org_profile_next" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised pull-right" data-perm="8">
          <div class="ico-btn">
            <i class="material-icons navigate">navigate_next</i>NEXT
          </div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/>Hello World<br/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there! Could you please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I copied your code into a BootPly, but it's impossible to work out the cause of the problem, as there is not enough relevant CSS -- http://www.bootply.com/jnwE9xmWV5

Comment: I have updated my classes and provided a link to an example that shows what I dont want to happen. @ObsidianAge

Comment: Well I discoverd a fix: If I added the affix class to the div with card class and set affix width: inherit !important; That did the trick in my example here: http://www.bootply.com/HuDVIMZMhe

Comment: you may want to add it as an answer, perfectly acceptable